# Extract a particular span

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to extract a value from a span from a url of a site but I can not isolate this particular value ....

here is the span in question

```
<span data-currency-market="" data-usd="63968175026.0">
```

I want the data-usd value only

```
 $html1 = file_get_contents( 'https://url.com' );
 $dom1 = new DOMDocument();
 @$dom1->loadHTML( $html1 );
 foreach ($dom1->getElementsByTagName('span') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue . '<br/>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_match_all like this

```
<?php

    // Loading data for demo
    $html1 = '[...]
    <span data-currency-market="" data-usd="63968175026.0"></span>
    <span data-currency-market="" data-usd="63968175026.0"></span>
    <span data-currency-market="" data-usd="63968175026.0"></span>';

    // Your data source
    //$html1 = file_get_contents( $string );

    preg_match_all('/usd="(.*)"/', $html1, $output_array);

    // Showing array
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($output_array);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Will output this:

[image]

If all you need are the numbers juste use

```
print_r($output_array[1]);
```

[image]

So at the end, all you need is 2 lines of code

```
$html1 = file_get_contents( $string );
preg_match_all('/usd="(.*)"/', $html1, $output_array);
```

You can use

```
foreach($output_array[1] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
}
```

to retreive the values

If you expect only one match in that page, you can use preg_match the same way like this instead of preg_match_all

```
<?php
    $html1 = '[...]
    <span data-currency-market="" data-usd="63968175026.0"></span>
    <span data-currency-market="" data-cad="73175026.0"></span>
    <span data-currency-market="" data-eur="83968176.0"></span>';
    //$html1 = file_get_contents( $string );
    preg_match('/usd="(.*)"/', $html1, $output_array);

    echo $output_array[1];
?>
```

Will output: 63968175026.0

Comment: No problem Chrys!

Comment: Just one last question, do you have an idea to rank my results in ascending order?

For example : 
$html1 = file_get_contents( $string );
preg_match_all('/usd="(.*)"/', $html1, $output_array); 

sort($output_array);

foreach($output_array[1] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
}

Answer (score 0):

To do it properly using DOM you can use XPath to find all span elements with a data-usd attribute.  The XPath is just `//span/@data-usd` where `@` denotes an attribute.  The call to `query()` returns a list of matching nodes, so you just loop through the same way as you did with `getElementsByTagName()`.

```
$html1 = '<div><span data-currency-market="" data-usd="1">
<span data-currency-market="" data-eur="2">
<span data-currency-market="" data-usd="3">
<span data-currency-market="" data-eur="4"></div>';

//$html1 = file_get_contents( 'https://url.com' );
$dom1 = new DOMDocument();
$dom1->loadHTML( $html1 );
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom1);
$dataUSD = $xp->query("//span/@data-usd");
foreach ($dataUSD as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

which with the test data returns...

```
1<br/>3<br/>
```